# Error while starting ejabberd with xml_rpc

Tags: xml-rpc, ejabberd

I try to configure xmlrpc in my ejabberd server but the server doesnt seem to start after configuring xmlrpc. My ejabberd config is :

```
{listen,[
{{4560, "127.0.0.1"}, ejabberd_xmlrpc, [
    {access_commands, [
      %% This bot can only execute the command 'register',
      %% and if argument 'host' is provided, it must be "example.org":
      {xmlrpcaccess, [register], [{host, "myhost.com"}]}
    ]}
  ]},
//many modules added here
]}.
{acl, xmlrpcbot, {user, "USER", "myhost.com"}}.
{access, xmlrpcaccess, [{allow, xmlrpcbot}]}.
```

and when I start service, I get the below log:

```
=INFO REPORT==== 2014-04-08 17:26:45 ===
application: ejabberd
exited: {bad_return,
         {{ejabberd_app,start,[normal,[]]},
          {'EXIT',
           {noproc,
            {gen_server,call,
             [ejabberd_sup,
              {start_child,
               {ejabberd_odbc_sup_localhost,
                {ejabberd_odbc_sup,start_link,["localhost"]},
                transient,infinity,supervisor,
                [ejabberd_odbc_sup]}},
              infinity]}}}}}
type: temporary
```

Of course the service runs if I comment all xml_rpc config lines. What's causing the error? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was also facing the same problem  when I tried to Configure Ejabberd_xmlrpc in configration file and was getting the same error as you have mentioned in your question,

When I look to the erlang error message "noproc"  means "trying to link to non exited process",above error says that there is some issue with your odbc configuration{this message seem eligible if you have configured to use mysql and not configured properly} but while using native db same error occurred than what is the real issue !!!!!!

I spent almost 2 days to solve this error by googling and doing try and error and found a post give on this [link](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.network.jabber.ejabberd/7740) by **Badlop**, thanks to him I finally solve this error.

I will go step by step process so that any new bee to ejabberd wants to configure ejabberd_xmlrpc will not get confused.

before going further I should mention my machine configuration 
I am using  **ubuntu 14.04** on my Dell 64-bit machine on which **ejabberd 2.1.11** is installed with **erlang version R16B03**.

On this [link](http://www.ejabberd.im/ejabberd_xmlrpc) official documentation of how to configure and use ejabberd_xmlrpc is given

details given on the above link are as below

> 1.You need to get and install XMLRPC-Erlang.
>
> ```
>  You can download XMLRPC-Erlang binary files from
>
>  http://www.ejabberd.im/ejabberd_xmlrpc           
>
>  or compile it yourself:
>
>  wget http://www.ejabberd.im/files/contributions/xmlrpc-1.13-ipr2.tgz
>
>  tar -xzvf xmlrpc-1.13-ipr2.tgz
>
>  cd xmlrpc-1.13/src
>
>  make
>
>  cd ../../
>
>  Then you can copy the *.beam files to ejabberd ebin directory,
>  or add an option like this to the ejabberd start script:
>
>  $ erl -pa '/home/jabber/xmlrpc-1.13/ebin' ...
> ```
>
> 2.Configure ejabberd to start this listener at startup:
>
> ```
>  edit ejabberd.cfg and add on the 'listen' section:
>     {listen, [
>       {4560, ejabberd_xmlrpc, []},
>         ...
>    ]}.   
>
> 3.Start ejabberd.
>
> 4. Verify that ejabberd is listening in that port.
> ```

Every thing  was working fine till step 3.

but after executing step 3

> ```
> $/etc/init.d/ejabberd start
> ```

Error occurs which says that server fails to start and look to ejabberd.log file for further information, The log file displays error @user3511518 has mentioned in his post.

**How to solve this error!!!!**

While reading **Badlop** answer I realized that I missed to include one file in jabberd/ebin and I have to compile ejabberd_xmlrpc.erl file.

**Badlop's answer**

> ```
> You're confused there.
> ```
>
> You have installed the xmlrpc library.
>
> Now you also need to compile ejabberd_xmlrpc.erl
>      Download it from http://www.ejabberd.im/ejabberd-modules

before going to http://www.ejabberd.im/ejabberd-modules link make sure you have install svn on your machine now follow the below step[same steps are given on above link].

> svn co https://svn.process-one.net/ejabberd-modules
>
> cd ejabberd-modules/ejabberd_xmlrpc/trunk
>
> ./build.sh

this will build ejabberd_xmlrpc.beam (compiled version of ejabberd_xmlrpc.erl)

> $ cd /(your current diectory)/ejabberd-modules/ejabberd/xmlrpc/trunk/ebin
>
> $ sudo mv ejabberd_xmlrpc.beam /home/jabberd/ebin[this is an example you have to move >this file to ebin folder of directory in which ejabberd is installed on your drive]

at the end restart your machine.

after rebooting check status of ejabberd by typing

> $sudo ejabberdctl status

if it shows running  than execute below command in your terminal

> netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN

If list shows

```
 tcp    0    0 0.0.0.0:4560   0.0.0.0:*       LISTEN
```

means your **xmlrpc** is running and listening to `http://hostname:4560`

please feel free to ask questions!!!!!

Hope this will solve your problem.