# Error after installing mod_xmlrpc in ejabberd

Tags: java, erlang, xml-rpc, ejabberd

I am working on a java project in which i have to communicate with the ejabberd (create/delete a jabber user etc.. ) xmpp server. From the different suggestions available in the internet I understood that xml rpc one method to achieve that.

I tried to install the mod_xmlrpc as per the suggesions in this thread. [Error while starting ejabberd with xml_rpc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22940797/error-while-starting-ejabberd-with-xml-rpc)

But I had failed to start the ejabberd after configuration of mod_xmlrpc. The ejabberd log says,

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 2015-03-15 20:23:27 ===
C(<0.42.0>:gen_mod:75) : Problem starting the module mod_adhoc for host "example.com" 
 options: []
 exit: {noproc,
       {gen_server,call,
           [ejabberd_iq_sup,
        {start_child,["example.com",mod_adhoc,process_local_iq]},
        infinity]}}

=ERROR REPORT==== 2015-03-15 20:23:27 ===
C(<0.42.0>:gen_mod:80) : ejabberd initialization was aborted because a module start failed.
```

and the erlang log says,

```
=CRASH REPORT==== 15-Mar-2015::20:23:27 ===
  crasher:
    initial call: supervisor:ejabberd_listener/1
    pid: <0.270.0>
    registered_name: []
    exception exit: {undef,
            [{ejabberd_xmlrpc,socket_type,[],[]},
             {ejabberd_listener,'-bind_tcp_ports/0-fun-0-',1,
                 [{file,"ejabberd_listener.erl"},{line,63}]},
             {lists,foreach,2,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1323}]},
             {ejabberd_listener,init,1,
                 [{file,"ejabberd_listener.erl"},{line,52}]},
             {supervisor,init,1,
                 [{file,"supervisor.erl"},{line,239}]},
             {gen_server,init_it,6,
                 [{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,304}]},
             {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,
                 [{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,239}]}]}
      in function  gen_server:init_it/6 (gen_server.erl, line 328)
    ancestors: [ejabberd_sup,<0.42.0>]
    messages: []
    links: [#Port<0.3747>,<0.234.0>,#Port<0.3744>]
    dictionary: []
    trap_exit: true
    status: running
    heap_size: 987
    stack_size: 27
    reductions: 1215
  neighbours:

=SUPERVISOR REPORT==== 15-Mar-2015::20:23:27 ===
     Supervisor: {local,ejabberd_sup}
     Context:    start_error
     Reason:     {undef,
             [{ejabberd_xmlrpc,socket_type,[],[]},
              {ejabberd_listener,'-bind_tcp_ports/0-fun-0-',1,
              [{file,"ejabberd_listener.erl"},{line,63}]},
              {lists,foreach,2,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1323}]},
              {ejabberd_listener,init,1,
              [{file,"ejabberd_listener.erl"},{line,52}]},
              {supervisor,init,1,[{file,"supervisor.erl"},{line,239}]},
              {gen_server,init_it,6,
              [{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,304}]},
              {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,
              [{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,239}]}]}
     Offender:   [{pid,undefined},
          {name,ejabberd_listener},
          {mfargs,{ejabberd_listener,start_link,[]}},
          {restart_type,permanent},
          {shutdown,infinity},
          {child_type,supervisor}]
```

Since I am a newbie to the ejabberd & erlang world I am finding it hard to track the root cause. Please help me to identify the root cause of this crash.

BTW is there any other method for communicating with ejabberd (create/delete a jabber user etc..) from java services ?

Comment: let me ask you what version of ejabberd are you using???

Answer (score 2):

The erlang log says that it can't find the function socket_type with no argument in the module ejabberd_xmlrpc. As it is a valid call, and both the module and function exist in the application [ejabberd](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd), this means that something went wrong during installation (compilation fails, wrong path ???)